# How to collect concise traffic statistics on linux?

Tags: linux, networking, traffic, tcpdump

I need to have statistics divided by time periods, like this:

```
time_1 - time_1 + 5mins
from_ip1 > to_ip2  total_packages_size1
from_ip3 > to_ip4  total_packages_size2

time_1 + 5mins - time_1 + 10mins
from_ip1 > to_ip2  total_packages_size3
from_ip5 > to_ip6  total_packages_size4
...
```

I looked at `tcpdump`, and I know how to get not summarized statistics with it. But I don't really want to make a tool which processes tcpdump logs and then clears them. There should be some ready-to-use tool for this standard problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do this with accounting rules in iptables.  I create a custom auditing rule

```
iptables -N GKT-AUDIT
```

I then send all traffic coming through, in this case, the `OUTPUT` chain, through that rule before anything else

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -j GKT-AUDIT
```

I then introduce rules **with no targets** into the `GKT-AUDIT` chain

```
iptables -A GKT-AUDIT -s 5.5.5.1 -d 7.7.7.2
iptables -A GKT-AUDIT -s 5.5.5.3 -d 7.7.7.4
```

and so on.  Since those rules have no targets, matching packets don't terminate but continue through the `GKT-AUDIT` chain, then fall out the end and return to the `OUTPUT` chain, so the rules have no effect on data flow.  But the packets **do** increment the packet counts of the matching rules on their way through, so I can slice and dice my traffic any way I want from a statistical basis.  I then usually collect them with a [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) plugin, and have munin graph them, but that's a refinement that may or may not suit you.

The nice thing about using iptables is that it can slice the traffic so many different ways, so I can be very precise about what traffic any particular rule matches: if I want to count only packets from a certain address, to a certain other address, but only on a certain source port range, and then only if it's part of a connection that has transferred in excess of 10MB, I can do that.

Comment: +1 for iptables! Go, iptables!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help you, but maybe it's worth looking into.

You can import raw tcpdump files in wireshark, thats a pretty nice tool. Not sure if
it's possible to use the summarized files though.

Regards, jgr

Answer (score 0):

What's your backend network infrastructure? Netflow was pretty much built for exactly the use case you're describing. It was developed by Cisco, but is available on most higher-end switches.

If you have to do this on the host level, this sounds like a job for [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/news.php). I don't think its reports get as incremental as you want, but you can probably tie into its Python API to get what you want.